# How to recover Deleted Files and Folders?

Tags: files, delete, restore

How I can restore files and folders.
I've deleted my home folder recursively. :(

Answer (score 9):

Trying to restore files and folders may become a hard and difficult task my friend, but you can find useful answers in this question: [Formatted and lost 6 years worth of photo memories.. any way to get this back?](https://askubuntu.com/q/32685/9598)

### [This is what I said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32685/formatted-and-lost-6-years-worth-of-photo-memories-any-way-to-get-this-back/32711#32711), and worked for me, placed here for your convenience:

*You may wish to take a look at this: [Recovering deleted data from deleted partition- solved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32685/formatted-and-lost-6-years-worth-of-photo-memories-any-way-to-get-this-back/32711#32711)*

*It's quite long, my personal experience when I accidentally removed the whole partition on a 500GB HDD.*

*The procedure I used is documented at the very bottom, placed here for your convenience:

*IMPORTANT: Try not to use forensic recovery procedures and not to use MS based recovery tools in the first instance.***

> 1. First of all you calm down.
>      Tranquil, if you erased or removed
>      the partition's table, the data is
>      still there. You need to find a way
>      to bring it back, that's it.
> 2. The most you can keep the drive off
>      new data, the best for your data. If
>      you write new data, the older data
>      will be replaced by the new as this
>      starts using the clusters.
> 3. If possible, try not using MS based
>      tools, which (in my case) just wrote
>      a few clusters in the disk which
>      made unusable some data. MS Recovery
>      Tools (such as Easy Data Recovery
>      and others) tries to read the
>      partition table but it also writes
>      some clusters which can't be fully
>      read in order to recover the "usable
>      part of the data". This may harm
>      your data replacing the original
>      allocation clusters with blank data
>      which allows the software to gain
>      access to the cluster itself.
> 4. Follow the instructions shown on the
>      [video documented by amzertech](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg&feature=player_embedded), which
>      was embedded in the [previous post](http://ultimateeditionisrael.freeforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=79&t=543)
>      and that clearly explains exactly
>      what I did in order to recover my
>      data.
> 5. If you follow these instructions, I
>      am sure you are going to succeed.
>      Even in the worst cases (how can a
>      different case than mine be worst?)
>      you will succeed if you follow this
>      easy instructions. Remember, the
>      data will remain intact if you leave
>      the disk intact. The most things you
>      do to the disk, will be the most
>      risk your data is reaching.

Anyway, this can be useful even if you deleted the whole partition (as I did then), and if you wish to run the risk to use forensic recovery procedures, I suggest you the usage of ***[foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/)***, which will bring back all the data you had stored in a specific place, but ***WARNING:*** This will bring back all the stuff that were saved into these folders since the beginning of the times.

Good luck!

Comment: Have you also tried Testdisk/Photorec apart from Foremost?

Comment: I haven't tested Photorec. The procedure that I talked about in my answer is Testdisk related, it did the gross of the work for me. Foremost was also useful and I started noticing about the existence of the Photorec when I gave this answer to @Lee Jarrat at http://askubuntu.com/questions/32685/formatted-and-lost-6-years-worth-of-photo-memories-any-way-to-get-this-back.

Comment: There is nothing dangerous on using foremost. When I have a need for file recovery on the disk on which Ubuntu is installed, I boot from a LiveCD and run foremost on it. I do not run is as root, I `chmod +r /dev/sdXY`, so I'm absolutely sure that the partition itself is not touched. For performance, write the data to another disk, e.g. an external HDD or 2nd internal HDD.

Comment: I agree to what @Lekensteyn says, that's why I suggested you the usage of foremost. But dropped a warning about MS based forensics recovery procedures/tools as these are which can be harmful for your data.

Comment: Testdisk was able to restore a partition I've formatted after choosing a clean install in Ubuntu 13.10 installation wizard. I've forgotten that Ubuntu wouldn't use the partition that I used to have Ubuntu 13.04 installed to make a clean install... it uses the whole HD (I had a second data partition that I didn't want to format). I needed to use Testdisk's Deeper Search and the option P (list files) to be able to write partition structure to disk. So, Testdisk has worked out even if I had mistakenly installed a new Ubuntu and swap partition.

Comment: Update: well, I had some problems with files recovered by Testdisk. Some of my folders are empty and a few files' got corrupted. Fortunately, my most important folders were not empty. Even so, I think Testdisk has made magic, once I had written my disk with a new Ubuntu installation and with a swap partition positioned at the end of the disk.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for your feedback @YuriC

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ext2, then you can use Midnight-Commander's Undelete function.

But the Debian versions used to have M-C compiled without it; maybe it's different now though.
So I used an old copy of Suse-8 [on another drive & which I keep for just that purpose].

So from then on [& forevermore] I shall stick to Ext2 for that reason.