# Accidentally deleted a folder

Tags: data-recovery

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 and accidentally deleted a folder using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Does anyone have any idea how to recover the folder?

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you can use `extundelete` command. (extundelete is a utility to recover deleted files from ext3/ext4 partition.)

> **Note that the partition must be unmounted before you recover.** In most cases, you will have to shut down your computer and boot using an Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveUSB to be able to this.

Steps to recover:

- Install *extundelete* with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install extundelete
  ```
- Usage example:

  ```
  sudo extundelete --restore-directory /home/myself/Documents/deleted_folder/ /dev/sda1
  ```
- The `/dev/sda1` is the device name where the deleted data was.

Comment: **Also note** that if installing extundelete touches the partition on which you want to recover data, the fact that changes were made to that partition *could* potentially make recovery more difficult.

Comment: @Frantique - I have run Ubuntu via LiveCD, but I can not install extundelete: E: Unable to locate package extundelete, how to solve this?

Comment: You have to enable universe repo to install it.

Comment: Didn't work for me on a remote VM. Running from a rescue system I've got some kind of "segmentation fault" errors. fsck didn't help. After reboot the deleted directory was still missing.

Comment: When I try thjis, it gives me this answer. Any idea why?  "extundelete: No such file or directory  /dev/sda5
extundelete: No such file or directory when trying to open filesystem /dev/sda5"

Comment: @pigwidgeon: the answer is there. Do you see the sda5 in /dev/ directory?