# Is it possible to unmount the /home partition?

Tags: mount, ext4, umount

I want to recover some files in my home directory using extundelete

http://sourceforge.net/projects/extundelete/

This tool needs to unmount the device before start to work, but I cannot umount /home:

```
$ sudo umount /home
umount: /home: not mounted
```

Comment: Execute `mount|grep /home` ... what is the output? If it's empty, `/home` is perhaps not on its own partition?!

Comment: Why not try Live cd/USB?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to remove the entry for /home from /etc/fstab (There will be a line there like this: /dev/sdb2 /home  ext2  rw  0  0), then reboot and log in as root. That way nobody is using anything on /home (logging in as a user will use your homedir on /home. This is the exception where you want to log in as root and not use su or sudo).

Answer (score 5):

You can enter single user mode for such operations by adding 's' to the end of grub boot line edit or run `sudo init 1`. there you can umount /home, if again get errors run `sudo umount -fl /home`. -f force and -l disconnect in lazy!

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: LOGGING IN TO A SYSTEM  AS ROOT MAY CAUSE VERY SERIOUS TROUBLE.**

Make sure /home is in its own partition, not just a directory under /.  to find out, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo df -l
```

You need to logged in as root to be able to accomplish your task.

to enable root account **(WARNING: NOT ADVISABLE)**, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo passwd root
```

You will have to enter a ppasword to complete the action.  Once you're done, **MAKE SURE THAT YOU DISABLE ROOT**,  by running:

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```

Answer (score 0):

To undelete files and directories from ext3/ext4 partitions using [extundelete](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/extundelete) [image: Install extundelete] or any other recovery software the partition where the files are on need to be unmounted. See also this question:

- [Accidentally deleted a folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150671/accidentally-deleted-a-folder)

However we can not unmount the partition where our OS or HOME resides while we had booted from this partition or are logged in to work in a HOME which may also be on a different partition. Only if the user we are logged in has their home on a partition different to the HOME we want to recover unmounting may be possible.

In all other cases any undelete or recovery needs to be performed from a **live system** booting Ubuntu from CD or USB choosing *"Try out Ubuntu"*. Then we also have to make sure to not mount our partitions while working in our live environment. Note that extundelete can be temporarily installed in a live sytem too.