# how to recover deleted files that are deleted using rm?

Tags: permissions

I have deleted text file using `rm`.
Now I have to recover it.
 How to recover it?

Comment: Gone forever, sorry. `rm` can be unforgiving. Hope you had backups.

Comment: Also, https://askubuntu.com/q/150671/158442 and the dupe targets of that.

Comment: Don't use "rm" if you wish to restore the files in future .You can use "rm-trash" utility :  https://github.com/nateshmbhat/rm-trash