# getting back my windows data!

Tags: data-recovery

Running out the door my foot grabbed the wire and my laptop to the floor. The hard drive ended up being the problem with the boot. Hard drive still spins so I know there's hope! Looking, I didn't find any data recovery programs for Ubuntu that I think could recover this particular data for me. And even if there was, the hard drive was running Windows 7 Home Edition and 6 years of data (some of which I paid for) from it.

So I figure it's probably best, since it's Windows 7, to run a Windows based data recovery program to best pull it off so I can convert all my 6 year prescious onto my new Ubuntu 12.04 only box.

Does anyone have any easy fast ways I can approach this with?

Comment: Hello. Welcome. Please let us know. The disk is spinning, but is it making a sound like a repeating click or another noise like it? If so, your hard disk drive may be in a major physical issue. Otherwise, there are good chances to bring your data back to live. :)

Comment: there's no clicking but there is some slowage in the spin speed of the hard drive due to a little inner drag. When I tried to reboot the disk in the original laptop it showed the windows screen but it was slow to load and it didn't load all the way till there was a black screen.. seems recoverable I think but Disk Utility doesn't show the disk's existence in the USB (where I have the HDD plugged in..

Comment: that's why I was thinking I need to run a windows program through wine maybe, to get the computer to see that drive??

Comment: Well, no... You have better chances to succeed if you do it in a native environment, both Windows and Linux tools will work the best if you run them in their respective environments. I suggest you to run a search for "data recovery" and pay special attention to those which refers to testdisk and photorec. Both tools are good for situations like yours. Foremost is another excellent tool. See this: http://askubuntu.com/a/33805/9598 and please inform on the evolution of your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Geppettvs D'... I'll try those ubuntu tools and let U know for sure. One more question if you don't mind.. I have the hard drive hooked up to a wire to USB and When I sudo lshw, it doesn't even see the existence of the drive, although on the bottom of the list, there is a strange element there.. doesn't say what it is, just some numbers.. That's where USB's usually show up so I think that might be it.. I'll let you know.. again, thanx!!!!

Comment: I suggest you to use a different cable and preferably hook it up directly in a motherboard via the proper cable. And please, I will be patiently waiting for your updates. geppettvs@geppettvs.x10.mx for email. Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)