# Contents of Downloads folder are gone ubuntu 12.04

Tags: directory

My downloads folder was there till evening. I went to my room and did a ssh onto my work machine and I find that the downloads folder is empty. I have some important files in downloads folder. Can anybody help me finding my contents?

Comment: Is the download folder gone or is it empty?

Comment: it is empty. there are no files there, but folder is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether your folder is hidden or not.
If it's not hidden than I think the folder has been deleted by mistake ..

So you can see the section for recovering files and folders here :

[How to recover Deleted Files and Folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders)