# Is it possible to restore missing Documents directory in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop computer?

Tags: boot, command-line, 16.04, kernel, python3

I have been running a tool which is saved in the `Documents` directory of my desktop computer. Suddenly my computer became unresponsive. So I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and then restarted the computer. After restarting my computer, I could not access my `Documents` directory, even though it was visible in my `Home` directory. I have typed the following command on my terminal and found the `Documents` directory, but I could not copy or move it:

```
ga@ga214:~$ locate Documents
/home/ga/Documents
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-documents:org.gnome.Documents.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/utopia-documents:UtopiaDocuments.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/UtopiaDocuments.png
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.portal.Documents.service
```

I could see the directory inside the `Home` directory as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: picture]

I have all my important data in `Documents`. If it is possible, please help me restore the directory with my data.

Comment: please provide us with the output of: ls -lia ~/Documents

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis , `ls -lia ~/Documents` command output as follows,                                    ```ga@ga214:~$ ls -lia ~/Documents
ls: cannot access '/home/ga/Documents': No such file or directory```

Comment: Also of note 16.04 is EOL in April time to think about upgrade.

Comment: @David, is it possible to recover my files or not?

Comment: your locate is responding with a probably out-of-date database. use the locate command again after-> sudo updatedb . also try the ls once more with sudo ls -lia /home/ga/Documents. if you don't have anything, the folder has been deleted.

Comment: What you see on the right side of your file browser are bookmarks that you added, that does not mean that their location exists. Also what Giorgos said, `locate` is using a database that might be outdatet, better use `find ~ -type d -name Documents`. If you click on "Home", you can check if a directory "Documents" is in there. I guess, ypi maybe accidently moved it somewhere (then you need to find it), or maybe you pressed Shift+Delete (then you deleted it for good and you must [use recovery software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders)).