# Messed up partition table accidentally

Tags: partitioning

I was using gparted software in ubuntu 11.10 (using live cd). In which there is an option called `create partition` table, i clicked it and it removed the details of my entire partition. Now i'm not able to see any of my partition (it has windows 7 installed and my personal files). But since i have not formatted my hard disk, i guess the data should be still there. Is there any way i can fix this partition table?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you to check this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg&feature=player_embedded which shows the correct usage of testdisk in order to fix situations like that. Which was really useful for me in the past when faced an issue like yours.

I am sure you'll be able to find a way to bring back your partition if you follow the easy steps provided in the video by amzertech.

Parts of my experience is documented in this answer [Formatted and lost 6 years worth of photo memories.. any way to get this back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32685/formatted-and-lost-6-years-worth-of-photo-memories-any-way-to-get-this-back/32711#32711), partially posted right here for your convenience:

> 1. First of all you calm down.
>      Tranquil, if you erased or removed
>      the partition's table, the data is
>      still there. You need to find a way
>      to bring it back, that's it.
> 2. The most you can keep the drive off
>      new data, the best for your data. If
>      you write new data, the older data
>      will be replaced by the new as this
>      starts using the clusters.
> 3. If possible, try not using MS based
>      tools, which (in my case) just wrote
>      a few clusters in the disk which
>      made unusable some data. MS Recovery
>      Tools (such as Easy Data Recovery
>      and others) tries to read the
>      partition table but it also writes
>      some clusters which can't be fully
>      read in order to recover the "usable
>      part of the data". This may harm
>      your data replacing the original
>      allocation clusters with blank data
>      which allows the software to gain
>      access to the cluster itself.
> 4. Follow the instructions shown on the
>      [video documented by amzertech](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg&feature=player_embedded)
>      and that clearly explains exactly
>      what I did in order to recover my
>      data.
> 5. If you follow these instructions, I
>      am sure you are going to succeed.
>      Even in the worst cases (how can a
>      different case than mine be worst?)
>      you will succeed if you follow this
>      easy instructions. Remember, the
>      data will remain intact if you leave
>      the disk intact. The most things you
>      do to the disk, will be the most
>      risk your data is reaching.