# Recovering Windows Partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-xp, data-recovery

How can I recover my Windows partition after installing Ubuntu 12.04 on the last partition of my HDD.  I desperately need to recover all the information on my Windows XP Home partition for schoolwork purposes.  When booting I can see the Windows XP partition, but cannot access it.  All I can do is boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello KevinB. Welcome to AskUbuntu. I am sorry you are in this situation, I have faced it in the past. First of all: Calm down. I suggest you to run a search for "data recovery" on this site, you'll find excellent answers to previous similar questions like this: http://askubuntu.com/a/79941/9598 and other provided for other users in different questions. I hope you are able to bring your data back without a major problem. Good luck! P.S. Oh! Well, if yours is a different situation other than "data recovery" don't hesitate to include that part in your answer in order to receive the best support.

Comment: If you actually installed Ubuntu *over* Windows, this may instead be a duplicate of: [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/286181/22949)

Answer (score 0):

If you dual booted it, you can go to File System and look for a folder called "host" in there should be all your stuff from xp, if you don't have that folder, you may need to do what  Geppettvs said.