# How can I recover my old windows 7 after Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, data-recovery

My OS is/was Windows 7, and I installed Ubuntu to lean a bit about Linux systems. After the installation I booted the computer and found I had no Windows access and I fear I have lost all my Windows data.

How can I recover the old Windows 7 and boot into it?

Or a the very least recover my windows 7 files.
I am a complete Linux novice so possible solutions will need to be simple.

Comment: How exactly did you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Assuming you chose to use the entire disk: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32685/formatted-and-lost-6-years-worth-of-photo-memories-any-way-to-get-this-back

Comment: Are you sure that you lost the Windows partition? Could you open the *disk* application, take a screen-shoot of your disk, upload it in [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) and link it here?

Comment: Or instead of providing a picture include the output of `sudo fdisk -l` . But if you chose use entire disk the file system has gone you may be able to get some of it back but not everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try use your CD/DVD installation/FD Drive where you install Ubuntu, then choose Try Ubuntu. Find your data, then copy to another drive. *edit:* If you can't, recheck using GParted Partition Editor.

Comment: When you install you can end up erasing entire disk so this may find nothing.  Open terminal CTRL+ALT+T and enter `sudo fdisk -l` enter your password.  Post the results.