# Lost all my data after changing Windows 8 to Ubuntu

Tags: installation, data-recovery

I need some help! I decided to change my win 8 to Ubuntu 12.10. In installation option I select the Change win 8 to Ubuntu. I had two partition C 50Gb and D 450 Gb. On C were the windows, and there I want to install the Ubuntu. But... after installation I haven't found my D partition just one was there 460 Gb. 
It's there some option to recover my dates, or all gone for all?

Comment: (I'm not sure if you got my chat message)  @learner When editing a question please look it over and make sure there aren't other issues that need to be fixed before submitting. I have approved [this one](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/94074) for now, but I was really on the fence. If you were fixing the only problem it would have been fine, but there were several others.

Comment: Sorry @Seth I will be more careful next time. Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

`testdisk` is a great tool to recover lost data and partitions. Install testdisk on a `live Ubuntu` and try to recover, I think in your case you will be able to recover all your data. Take care ;)

Comment: Yes now I tired that, I’m curios what will happened. I Don’t want to loose all my date. I want to install on the C partition and the ubuntu take all, I don’t understand that.

Comment: edited my answer ;)

Comment: That's mean to install testdisk on an Ubuntu witch is on USB. very cool I have a cool job tonight :)) Now run the Analyze Cylinder, it is very long time.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done many things to your disk drive, other than installing, you have good chances to bring back the whole partition, run a backup and then reinstall everything. Check the answers to previous questions under "data-recovery" and other related tags.

Parts of this answer comes from **[this previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/32711/9598)**.

IMPORTANT: Try not to use forensic recovery procedures and not to use MS based recovery tools in the first instance.

> 1. First of all you calm down.
>      Tranquil, if you erased or removed
>      the partition's table, the data is
>      still there. You need to find a way
>      to bring it back, that's it.
> 2. The most you can keep the drive off
>      new data, the best for your data. If
>      you write new data, the older data
>      will be replaced by the new as this
>      starts using the clusters.
> 3. If possible, try not using MS based
>      tools, which (in my case) just wrote
>      a few clusters in the disk which
>      made unusable some data. MS Recovery
>      Tools (such as Easy Data Recovery
>      and others) tries to read the
>      partition table but it also writes
>      some clusters which can't be fully
>      read in order to recover the "usable
>      part of the data". This may harm
>      your data replacing the original
>      allocation clusters with blank data
>      which allows the software to gain
>      access to the cluster itself.
> 4. Follow the instructions shown on the
>      [video documented by amzertech](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg&feature=player_embedded), which
>      was embedded in the [previous post](http://ultimateeditionisrael.freeforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=79&t=543)
>      and that clearly explains exactly
>      what I did in order to recover my
>      data.
> 5. If you follow these instructions, I
>      am sure you are going to succeed.
>      Even in the worst cases (how can a
>      different case than mine be worst?)
>      you will succeed if you follow this
>      easy instructions. Remember, the
>      data will remain intact if you leave
>      the disk intact. The most things you
>      do to the disk, will be the most
>      risk your data is reaching.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for help. The testdisk just found the existing one partition, nothing else.

Comment: In certain cases, you must delete your current partitions in order to allow testdisk find anything else. Use at your own risk. It worked for me in the past. Good luck!