# I Installed Ubuntu and now my Windows 7 is gone

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, data-recovery

I just downloaded ubuntu yesterday then i installed it (Ubuntu 12.10

I did not do any partitions just automatic installing it

Is it completely gone?

Uhm i have my games inside the C:\

I wanted to play it on Ubuntu

Where can i find my games :)

Please answer thank you :)

Comment: further information, e.g, what version of Ubuntu you installed (and if indeed it was Ubuntu Server), might aid the community to help you out.

Comment: If you are thinking of playing your windows games on ubuntu well bad news you cant! And it looks like you have overwritten ubuntu on windows.

Comment: @AkasAntony - That's not entirely true. Most games run just fine with the help of Wine. He might still have to reinstall them, though, but that's more due to how Windows applications install.

Comment: If your look in explorer (nautilus). Do you see some other partions?

Comment: I used Ubuntu 12.10 Sorry for the server wrong tag.
Well my friend said i can play it on ubuntu
@Thomas15v What do you mean Thomas i'm new to ubuntu

Comment: On the left side there is some folder icon. Click it. On the left side of the program that will be opened there will be a tab "devices" there sould be something like "volume off 444gb"

Comment: @Thomas15v Sorry i don't see anything.

Comment: Than you have overwritten your windows 7 diffenly. And that is a little bad i think. Also your files and savedata from your games are gone forever. For ubuntu I installed it 4 times before I actually started to use it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have erased your Windows. Check [how to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) to learn more about dual-boot installing, and the answers [given to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263962/lost-all-my-data-after-changing-windows-8-to-ubuntu) to try to recover your data.

In order to run Windows programs, you would have to [install Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine) and then install the applications there.

Comment: Well i already installed it :(
and I can't access windows 7 :(

Comment: check the second link, they asked how to recover windows data: http://askubuntu.com/questions/263962/lost-all-my-data-after-changing-windows-8-to-ubuntu

Comment: That link is how to install. MY ubuntu is already installed.
I want to recover my files :c

Comment: My mistake. I have updated the link both in the answer and in the comment. Sorry.

Comment: I will try it dude ;). I'm installing testdisk for now.

Comment: Also, in the chance that you didn't erase your Windows partition, you're a) not going to have a "C:\" drive/partition in Ubuntu, because Ubuntu doesn't partition like that; and b) you won't be able to play your Windows games straight from that drive, anyway (unless they do like Blizzard does with World of Warcraft, which, in my experience, is rare; there's often more to installing a game than just copying files). To save yourself the headache when you get there, look up "how to I run windows applications on ubuntu?".

Comment: I know how to run windows application on ubuntu the wine app one.
I'm not sure on how to use this testdisk

Comment: Hey dude my disk won't appear but my usb appears
`some disk won't appear unless you are root user.`

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing how you installed Ubuntu it is hard to answer this.

The default choice in the Ubuntu installer is "Install alongside Windows", and it will shrink the size of the Windows partition *(if there is room and it is not messed up)* and then create a Linux partition and install there. If you did that, your windows is there, and you can boot into Ubuntu on your hard drive, and restore grub by clicking on the terminal then typing:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then, reboot.

If you did **not** select the default "Install alongside Windows", you may have erased windows and replaced it with just Ubuntu. If you did, reinstall Windows, then install Ubuntu again *in that order*.

P.S. To be safe, you should always backup your drive before installing a new OS or new version of an OS.

Comment: Sir i tried the sudo update-grub
and the infos is like this
`Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin`

Comment: if it did not find windows, you erased windows. period. Sometimes, you can immediately shutdown the moment you discover this huge oops, and recover some of the files via testdisk... but it is not easy, not easy to explain.. and sometimes recovers some of your files. 
In the future, read and consider the questions asked, and always backup before an OS install. 
RedoBackup from redobackup.org is free and will allow you to backup your entire drive nicely (Windows, Linux, Mac all three) if you have an external drive big enough, or are network savy.

Answer (score 0):

You erased it, if you use automatic installation, all partitions will be erased and used for Ubuntu.

Comment: So there's no way to recover my files back?

Comment: There is a way - testdisk, but it there is great chance, that you overwrote some data from the old partition, so you won't be able to recover everything

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it looks like you just have Linux on there now.

To see what partitions you actually have, type in the terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -lu
```

But it looks to me like you used the whole drive and all the Windows data is gone.  When you install, you reformat.  Testdisc won't help you with a low level format.

Comment: is this the results    
`
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   621090815   310544384   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       621092862   625141759     2024449    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       621092864   625141759     2024448   82  Linux swap / Solaris
`

Comment: Please help me sir :( On the testdisk i'm on 6500/38000
It's too long sir please help me T_T
I just want my games to be recovered

Comment: Testdisk *will* still help even after repartitioning, it's just not guaranteed to work, and if you've written over some of the old data, you're highly unlikely to recover all of it.

Answer (score -1):

If you locate the disk application in Ubuntu (either search in the menu or download if necessary in the app store or Synaptic package manager), it will display the format of your current partition, from there you can select to allow the largest disk within your partition to boot windows NFTS (it is imperative you choose this boot format) and once you change it to allow that boot mode you can restart your computer and load windows onto your device with the OS CD. Then once you have the system loaded onto your device you can proceed to re-install Linux.

Hope this works for you!